# Make nginx the owner of a file when mounting to VBOX

Tags: mount, virtualbox, macintosh, shared-folders

My issue is when I mount a folder from my desktop to virtualbox on Mac osx Yosemite It sets the permissions to drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root

Using the command: sudo mount -t vboxsf sharename mountpoint

This command made the permissions set to root root. Is there a way to mount the folder so that the permissions will read drwxr-xr-x. 1 root nginx ?

Comment: It looks like this is tagged Linux. Just so I'm clear, where's the Linux system in this?

Comment: It appears I tagged linux instead of mac by mistake. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to make an entire volume writable by your webserver UID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy of [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/527963/how-to-allow-nginx-in-guest-vm-access-shared-folders-in-host-os):

The solution was

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf sharename -o rw,dmode=777,gid=(root user),uid=(nginx) /var/virtual/some_folder_name
```

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
usermod -a -G vboxsf nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the owner of file/directory using command

> chown

Comment: This doesn’t necessarily work on a mount point, and in particular in the context of this question I don’t think it will (have you tested it?).